# ColdFusion CFCHART Pie Chart Data Label Position

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfchart

I have created a pie chart using the cfchart tag and as of the moment the labels for the chart data show outside of the pie chart, where I would like them placed inside each respective slice.  I've looked through CF documentation but can seem to find a easy way to accomplish this.  Can anyone shed some light on how I can just make the labels show inside each slice of the pie rather than outside?

Thank you!!!

I've tried using the following code and then using the cxml variable as the value for the style attribute on the cfchart tag.  This does indeed set the labels inside the slices, but it also makes the pie chart have an odd shading to it.  In addition, before applying this style I can set a value for the url parameter of the cfchart tag and cause a javascript function to fire when each slice is clicked.  With the style applied, it's like it breaks each slice into separate clickable areas.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="cxml">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pieChart depth="Plain" style="Solid" is3D="false">
    <dataLabels style="value" placement="Inside" foreground="white" font="Arial-12"/>
</pieChart>
</cfsavecontent>


<cfchart format="png" style="#cxml#"....>
```

Comment: Please post the code that shows your attempt to create labels for your chart.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but the `<?xml` line should usually be the very first thing in an XML doc - so either put it immediately after the `>` for savecontent, or use `trim(cxml)` to remove the linebreak that it currently has...

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? There was a pretty big change from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 10

Comment: ColdFusion Version 8.

Comment: Got it working by using the webcharts3D application that ships with ColdFusion.

Comment: @Phil - Please post a snippet of your final code as an "answer", to help others that run into the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the WebCharts3D application that ships with ColdFusion 8, I was able to copy the XML.
The following is what worked for me:

```
        <cfsavecontent variable="cxml">
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <pieChart depth="Plain" style="Solid" is3D="false">
        <legend spacing="0" placement="Right" font="Dialog-11">                 
            <decoration style="None" />
        </legend>            
        <paint palette="PastelTransluent" paint="Plain" min="44" max="95"/>
        </pieChart>
        </cfsavecontent>
```